# openbsd: mpls provider doesn't forward packets

Tags: networking, openbsd, forwarding

Can anybody help me with next question:

I am trying to get mpls test network up like in http://lteo.net/blog/2013/09/03/a-small-mpls-test-network-built-with-openbsd/ or http://2011.eurobsdcon.org/papers/jeker/MPLS.pdf.

Configuration seems to be identical.
I can see that lpd and ospf works because in routing table I can see new entries when I turn those services on.

When I use tcpdump to capture packets on hosts like P (provider) on incoming interface connected to PE(provider edge) I can detect mpls packets.

On outgoing interface those packets does not appear, but counter in (netstat -r) shows that packet number forwarded increased on appropriate rules.

Excuse me for my English and thank You for your time.